# How to parse KLV formatted byte array using C#

Tags: c#, arrays, byte

I am working on a PC hosted application which communicates to an embedded device. The application and the embedded device communicates with an UART interface. The communication protocol states that the data payload is formatted in KLV format. The host PC is written in C# and it can receive the hex data from device and put them into a byte array now. But I am not sure how to parse data. Also I am wondering how to compose the KLV data if I need to send some data to device.

Comment: It might help if you can show a small sample of your KLV data as received (at least in bytes as hexadecimal).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an UART interface between the devices I doubt you receive 'hex'. Hex is just the representation often used for bytes itself. However as you have written it is already converted to bytes (e.g. by [BitConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter?view=net-6.0) class - strongly recommend taking a look in it).

Regarding the KLV format - i hope this is referring to the key-length-value protocol. Somewhere should be a document exactly descriping what data you get, because this protocol is often dimplemented different in following terms.

In the basics it is like: [KEY][LENGTH of VALUE][VALUE]. If you convert ([Encoding.GetString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getstring?view=net-6.0), e. g. Encoding.ASCII.GetString()) everything to string you should already see some readable data (also I found that some folks used numbers for keys).

So you need the documentation about:

- What KEYs are sent (mostly all have got the same length)
- What data types you receive in VALUE for each Key

Without this information, you have to listen to the device for some time and afterwards analyse the data.